# Collection<T> class and it's use

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I came across the following code:

```
var collection = new Collection<string>();
```

I haven't seen the Collection class used too much, and can't find too much information about its purpose. Looking at the .NET Framework source, it's pretty much just a wrapper around a List as it stores a List member field. Its constructor is as follows:

```
public Collection()
{
  this.items = (IList<T>) new List<T>();
}
```

And it also implements IList. So you can declare the Collection as:

```
IList<string> collection = new Collection<string>();
```

Which to me is functionally equivalent to creating a List instead:

```
IList<string> collection = new List<string>();
```

So when would you ever want to use it over a List in your own code? I see that it is a base class for other .NET collections, but why would they include this as a **public concrete** (as opposed to internal and/or abstract)?

---

*Regarding comments around possible duplicates* -- the answers to related questions seem to say that Collection class is supposed to be used as a base class. What I'm really asking that's different is:

1. If using in your own code, why not use List as a base class instead?
2. Does it really ever make sense to instantiate a new Collection in
   your own code in place of List?
3. If it really is **only** provided to serve as a base class, **why is it not abstract**?

Comment: are you searching for this ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really like answering my own questions, but as far as Q3 is concerned I believe I understand the reasoning. I got it while looking at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/585476.aspx) referenced in Bas Paap's answer.

In short, the reason the Collection class is not abstract is because you may want to leave yourself the option of deriving from the class at a later date. In the meantime, you can use it as a return type and instantiate it directly. [The link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/585476.aspx) shows a code example where this is the case.

I've upvoted all other answers that I thought addressed the issues raised in the question.

Comment: I'm still not convinced about Q3. While the linked post pictures a feasible scenario, I'd hardly call it a satisfactory answer. I mean, the problem could as easily be solved by exposing a member of type `IList<T>` (AFAIK `Collection<T>` does not expose any additional members to those required by `IList<T>`), and `Collection<T>` being abstract or not would have no significance. And while being able to instantiate `Collection<T>` might be convenient at certain times, it somewhat obscures its main purpose of being a base class for custom collections.

Answer (score 20):

I think the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) itself already names the most important aspects (highlights by me):

> The Collection class **provides protected methods** that can be used **to**
>    **customize its behavior** when adding and removing items, clearing the
>   collection, or setting the value of an existing item.

and

> Notes to Implementers
>
> This base class is provided to make it easier for implementers to
>   create a custom collection. **Implementers are encouraged to extend this
>   base class instead of creating their own.**

**[EDIT for ypur updated questions]**

> *1. If using in your own code, why not use List as a base class instead?*

`Collection<T>` provides some protected methods so you can easily `override` the behavior and completely enroll your own business logic, like:

- `ClearItems()`
- `InsertItem()`
- `RemoveItem()`
- `SetItem()`

`List<T>` does not provide them and has almost no protected methods to overrides behavior, which makes customizing it harder.

> *2. Does it really ever make sense to initialize a new Collection in your own code in place of List?*

No, not just for the sake of initializing some collection. Use it if you need it *as a base class for implementing your own logic*.

This will depend on your own business needs. For almost all cases in daily development work, the existing - and numerous - collections should already provide what you need. There are type safe and untyped collections, thread-safe collections, and whatever else you can think of.

Still, one day there may be a demand for implementing a collection type that does certain valididation checks before it allows to add/update/delete any items in it or that handles moving to the next item in a only sparsely populated list in a specail manner. You never know what ideas a customer may have.

In those case it might help to create your own collection type.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ... I wonder why, then, the Collection class is not abstract?

Comment: @ZaidMasud: This is just a guess, but I would think that this is to save you from implementing the *core functionality* and to allow you to only focus on implementing your own logic **where it differs** from the basic functionality.

Comment: An abstract class can have non-abstract virtual methods, so what you are saying can be accomplished via an abstract class.

Answer (score 9):

The [Collection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) class is the base class for a whole bunch of other collection classes.
The [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class, is a class that is optimized for speed, and the Collection class, is designed for extensibility.

When you look at the members of `Collection(T)`, you'll see that it contains some additional protected virtual methods (like [`InsertItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132412.aspx)) that the `List(T)` class doesn't have.

In fact, I've created an instance of the Collection class.  I think I would only use this type as a parameter in a method signature, just to not tightly couple the method with the implementation of the collection (if possible).

To answer your questions:

1. I would use `Collection(T)` as a base class, because it's the
   intention of that class to be used as a base class for other
   collection types.  It offers you more flexibility (see the protected
   virtual methods `InsertItem`, `RemoveItem` and `SetItem`)
2. When in need of a collection, I would use an instance of the
   `List(T)` class, since it is optimized for speed.
3. Actually, I wonder why they haven't made the `Collection(T)`
   class abstract.

Answer (score 7):

As Krzysztof Cwalina [puts it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx):

> •List is not designed to be extended. i.e. you cannot override any members. This for example means that an object returning List from a property won’t be able to get notified when the collection is modified. Collection lets you overrides SetItem protected member to get “notified” when a new items is added or an existing item is changed.
>
> •List has lots of members that are not relevant in many scenarios. We say that List is too “busy” for public object models. Imagine ListView.Items property returning List with all its richness. Now, look at the actual ListView.Items return type; it’s way simpler and similar to Collection or ReadOnlyCollection.

For this reason, FxCop's rule CA1002 also tells you not to expose generic Lists and use Collection instead. See also this [Code Analysis Team Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/585476.aspx) about the FxCop rule and why to return Collection rather than List.

So for question 1 and 2, see above. As for question three, it's not just there to serve as a base class. You're supposed to be able to instantiate it and use it as a return type as well, hence it's not abstract.

Comment: Your answer makes sense for Q1&2. For Q3 I don't follow your reasoning. You don't need to instantiate something to use it as a return type, an abstract class can be used as a return type.

Comment: After I read your Code Analysis Team Blog post link, this blog post actually answers Q3 for me (although you haven't stated the reason in your answer).

Comment: Like I said, you're supposed to be able to instantiate it and use it as a return type. I'm not sure how this is a different answer than your own accepted answer of "In the meantime, you can use it as a return type and instantiate it directly.", but yeah. I figured the ability to derive from it was apparent from the blog post I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Although the enumeration interfaces provides a forward-only iteration over a collection, they do not provide a mechanism to determin the size of a collection, access a member by index, search, or modify the collection. For such functionality, the framework provides the `ICollection`, `IList` and `IDictionary` interfaces.

`ICollection<T>` provides medium functionality (for example the `Count` property).

`IList<T>` and their non-generic version provide maximum functionality (including 'random' access by index).

It is rare that you will need to *implement* any of these interfaces. In almost all cases when you need to write a collection class, you can instead subclass `Collection<T>` etc.

I hope this helps.