# How to implement an interface member correctly?

Tags: c#, collections

I am coding a simple application that works with collections. How do I properly implement an interface method in the case below? Currently, it shows an error "not all code paths return a value".

This is my home task. The class "Time" is already implemented and works properly. I tried to find any examples of successful implementation of this method on the Internet but failed.

```
class MyCollection : ICollection<Time> 
    {
        List<Time> arr = new List<Time>();

        int ICollection<Time>.Count
        {

            get
            {
                arr.Count();
            }    
        }
     }
```

I am getting an error:

> CS0161 "MyCollection.ICollection.Count.get': not all code paths
>   return a value"

Comment: You aren't returning the value: `return arr.Count();` However, a bigger question is why are you using `MyCollection` in the first place, when using a plain `List<>` would likely work just as well?

Comment: Indeed, why create your own `MyCollection`? Are you trying to replace some `List<T>` functionality? If you want to add a few methods on top of a `List<Time>` or  `IEnumerable<Time>` you can create an extension method

Comment: Thanks for answer! Actually there will be other custom methods like filling the collection with random elements, and sorting it by certain fields. And the overall task is creating an event-controlled application, which is why 'MyCollection' is required instead of just 'List', i guess

Comment: You can still have functions that do all that, they don't need to be inside the class, in fact I would argue that they are *not* in the class as they are not relevant.

Comment: @ArianLyn those have nothing to do with `ICollection<T>` then, Those are factory or controller or some other type of methods that *use* a collection. In fact, in an event-based application I'd except ReactiveX and Observables to be used

Comment: If you want to write your own collection, it is highly recommended to inherit from ```Collection<T>``` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12070121/2194443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, you can use [Expression body definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties) `=>`

```
class MyCollection : ICollection<Time>
{
    List<Time> arr = new List<Time>();

    int ICollection<Time>.Count => arr.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `return` statement on your getter .

```
class MyCollection : ICollection<Time> 
{
    List<Time> arr = new List<Time>();

    int ICollection<Time>.Count
    {

        get
        {
            return arr.Count();
        }    
    }
 }
```

Comment: Actually `Count()` is acceptable, it's a Linq method.

Comment: Calling `List.Count()` works exactly the same because `Count()` is a LINQ method that actually checks whether the input is an `ICollection` and calls `ICollection.Count` in that case

Comment: @DavidG Ammended